# check if there is a next() function express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

is there a way to see if there is a function after the current middleware.
ie

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    if(next){//always returns true
    }
});
```

I have a function to fetch the information and depending on the route that information will either be displayed in a table or a form or it will be combined with other data.

I wanted to have a function similar to

```
function findAll(req, res, next){
    db.findAll(function(err, docs){
        if(next){
            req.list = docs
            return next();
        }else{
            res.render('table', {list:docs};
        }
    });
}
```

that way I could use the same function in either

```
router.get('/', findAll, handleData);
```

or

```
router.get('/', findAll);
```

and in either case a response will be sent. is there a way i can define the stack for the router like express does in the next() handler

example

```
var layer = stack[idx++];
```

this catches the next function if it exists but I cannot access this scope from my function. is there a way i can define the layers myself.

This seems like it could be very usefull in preventing redundant code

Comment: By design, isn't there always a `next()` for middleware in express? You could also succinctly select view properties by having a function that returns the actual view function in a closure context.

Comment: thats what im asking the ways its designed you can always call next but is there a way to find out if the function running is the last in that chain

Comment: @paul wonderful idea

Answer (score 3):

thanks to paul i was able to work around the next issue kind of.
currently this working

```
function findAll(callback){
    return function send(req, res){
        db.findAll(function(err, docs){
            if(callback){
                req.docs = docs
                return callback(req, res, next());
            }
            res.render('table', {docs:docs});
        });
    }
}
function handleData(req, res, next){
    res.send(req.docs);
}
```

will work with

```
router.get('/', findAll());
```

or

```
router.get('/', findAll(handleData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Snymax
You can check in the function if next is defined or not.
If defined you can call next and
if not do what you want.

WORKED FOR ME.

```
    function findAll(req, res, next){
      db.findAll(function(err, docs){
        if(typeof next != "undefined"){
            req.list = docs
            return next();
        }else{
            res.render('table', {list:docs};
        }
      });
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

typeof next != 'undefined' will always be True. So answer is not good.

first you need to use '!==' because yu compare the type.

i guess next its a promise or something , so youll always get something if you try to get the type from it